# round based on column value in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rounding

I need to round off summary_measure_value based on reading_precision value

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(
[(123, 2897402, 43.25, 2),
(124, 2897402, 49.25, 0),
(125, 2897402, 43.25, 2), 
(126, 2897402, 48.75, 0)]
, ['model_id','lab_test_id','summary_measure_value','reading_precision'])


partition_by_reading = [
    "model_id",
    "lab_test_id"
]
df.withColumn(
        "reading_value",
        round(avg("summary_measure_value").over(
                    Window.partitionBy(partition_by_reading))
                ,col("reading_precision"))).show()
```

I'm getting TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Make sure that you properly format your code and results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pyspark [`round`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.round.html) function expects a constant value for the scale/precision. You may have better luck creating a custom udf that applies the rounding logic.

I've included an example below from a test I've done based on your shared example :

```py
udf_round = F.udf(lambda val,precision: round(val,precision))
df.withColumn(
        "reading_value",
        udf_round(F.avg("summary_measure_value").over(
                    Window.partitionBy(partition_by_reading))
                ,F.col("reading_precision"))).show()
```

NB. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) in the udf above refers to the built-in python [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function.

result:

| model_id | lab_test_id | summary_measure_value | reading_precision | reading_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 2897402 | 43.25 | 2 | 43.25 |
| 124 | 2897402 | 49.25 | 0 | 49.0 |
| 123 | 2897402 | 43.25 | 2 | 43.25 |
| 126 | 2897402 | 48.75 | 0 | 49.0 |

Edit 1:

If you have erroneous data the following udf is more robust

```py
@udf
def udf_round(val,precision) -> float:
    try:
        # ensure that value is a float and precision is an integer
        return float(round(float(val),int(precision)))
    except:
        return val # return val if there are any errors
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: a float is required

Comment: The round function being called within the udf based on your code is the pyspark round and not the python round. By importing all pyspark functions using `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` you have overridden/hidden the implementation with the builtin python round function with the round function imported from pyspark. This import `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` is the recommended approach as it allows you to import and reference pyspark functions without polluting/overriding the global namespace i.e there is a difference between round and F.round

Comment: I figured I had a lot of NNULL values in summary_measure_value column. The edit worked. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, applied a pandas_udf iterating multiple series. Seems faster than I thought

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import *
from typing import Iterator, Tuple
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col


@pandas_udf('double')
def round_series(iterator: Iterator[Tuple[pd.Series, pd.DataFrame]]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    return(a.round(b) for a,b in iterator)

df1=df.withColumn("reading_value",F.avg("summary_measure_value").over( Window.partitionBy("model_id", "lab_test_id"))).withColumn("reading_value",round_series('summary_measure_value','reading_precision')).show()

+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|model_id|lab_test_id|summary_measure_value|reading_precision|reading_value|
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|     123|    2897402|                43.25|                2|        43.25|
|     124|    2897402|                49.11|                1|         49.1|
|     125|    2897402|                43.25|                2|        43.25|
|     126|    2897402|                48.75|                0|         49.0|
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```